# Cannot read property 'getModelManager' of undefined in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

When I am trying to upload the stored bna file from my local storage to composer playground, I see below error:-  "cannot read property 'getModelManager' of undefined"

[image]

Can someone tell me why I am seeing this error?

Comment: have you tried to deploy the bna (you mention) from the 'browse local' option in Playground? The screenshot suggests you're trying to create a new business network. Are you following a particular tutorial? How did you create the .bna file you mention? What version of Composer / Playground - assume this is a local playground? not enough detail

Comment: Yes Paul you are right, I was not creating the business network archive file which is to be used for upgrading network chaincode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when composer playground is used to create the project, make sure that business network archive file is created which is then uploaded for install/update the existing network.

[click here for document on upgrading existing network!](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/upgrading-bna)